# Writing Urdu Text On Images in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am writing English Text on Images in Python using PIL.Selecting Text, Font, and image dynamically.it is working fine.

Now I would like to do the same with Urdu text, since Urdu follows RTL, my program is not rendering it correctly. I have the required fonts etc But it does not add the text correctly to the image.

The below image is the reqired result but generated text makes each character appear individually just like LTR languages.

Am I missing some encoding script etc.?

For Examples
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and use a unicode compatible font, in my case [arial](https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/88978/arial-unicode-ms):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
image = Image.new("RGB",[320,320])
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
a = u"Urdu text بے-اعیند ز "

font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\\Users\\Home\\Downloads\\arial-unicode-ms.ttf",14)
draw.text((50, 50), a, font=font)
image.save("image.png")
```

[image: urdu text]

Comment: My Urdu Text looks the same as yours, And i think its not correct.

Comment: You Can see that, its not showing the added text correctly!

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

text_string = u'تصوير'

img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 150))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('jameel.ttf', 50)

draw.text((25,40), text_string, fill='white', font=font)

img.show()
```